# When printing large data frames to console, R starts working unbearably slowly - how can I fix it?

Tags: r, performance, printing, console

I'm running R on a Mac (OS X). I have a rather large data frame (imported from a csv-file) that I'm working with:

```
dim(mydf)
[1] 75848     9
```

I'm trying to analyse it and find ways of breaking it up into smaller parts, so I need to print at least parts of it out to get an overview from time to time.

However, when I have printed it, R (version 3.1.2) starts working extremely slowly to the point where I just have to give up and restart it. Then R works normally until I have printed something large to the console again.

I have tried ´gc()´ and ´rm(list = ls())´, but it doesn't improve the speed - and I guess it wouldn't as it seems to be the printing to the console and not the size of the data frame that causes the slowness (clogging up memory?).

Is there anything I can do to prevent R from becoming so slow, or do I just have to choose between restarting frequently or giving up printing my data to the console?

Thanks!

Comment: Look into `data.table` or `dplyr`.  Both make managing large data frames a lot easier.

Comment: what is the point in printing something that takes up more than one or two windows much less an entire large data frame? use `head` or `summary` or the many `split-apply-combine` methods to get your overview

Answer (score 1):

Same as you, I wanted to get an overview of my data. But just a little more then the ‘head’ function would give me. So I wrote a small function that would give me the head, middle, and tail of a dataset.

```
hmt <- function(x){ # head, middle, tail of data set
if(class(x) == "data.frame"){
middle <- round(nrow(x)*0.5)
middle <- x[(middle-3):(middle+3),]
data <- rbind(head(x),middle,tail(x))
}
return(data)
}

hmt(cars)
```

And the result:

```
   speed dist
1      4    2
2      4   10
3      7    4
4      7   22
5      8   16
6      9   10
22    14   60
23    14   80
24    15   20
25    15   26
26    15   54
27    16   32
28    16   40
45    23   54
46    24   70
47    24   92
48    24   93
49    24  120
50    25   85
```

Hope this is of any help to you.

Comment: Sometimes, I just print the first 5 - 10 rows. My data has mixed factors, including strings, so I need more of an overlook than just what summary or head can give.